# Spring Data JPA Repository CRUD Testing

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm playing around with the Spring Data Repository and have a question on writing CRUD tests.  I have written many CRUD tests against Hibernate DAOs and EJB 3 entity beans where I create and entity, flush it to the database, clear the entity manager, and read it back by ID.  The entity manager is cleared so the first level cache is not hit on the read.

Using the Spring Data repository I can't find a way to clear the underlying entity manager used by my test so my read is not going back to the actual database, making my test invalid.

Is there any way to clear the entity manager in the test?  Is there a way I can inject one into my test so that it is used by the repository?

Thanks!

Cory.

Comment: Why do you think you need to interact with the `EntityManager`? Wouldn't you rather simply have a transaction per test method and roll that one back after the method finished? The Spring testing framework does that out of the box. See an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/example/src/test/java/example/springdata/jpa/simple/SimpleUserRepositoryTests.java).

Comment: After I create the entity and flush it I want to clear the EntityManager so I know the read will actually execute a select on the DB and not just find the entity I just created from the first level cache.

Comment: If you turn on SQL logging, you should be able to confirm that the database is being selected from on the read.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by injecting the entitymanager like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager
```

and make your test transactional by setting the @Transactional attribute on your test method. Then inside the method you can call the entityManager.flush() method.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you wish the EntityManager to be cleared automatically you can set @Modifying annotation’s clearAutomatically attribute to true.
[Please see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)